# Publish a message from global scope in python

Tags: ros, python2.7, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently Trying to make this rosnode work, but I aren't sure why i am not able to do the first publish in this code, being the pub.publish(String("start"))
But able to do the ones in the callback, what is wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
from std_msgs.msg import Int8
from std_msgs.msg import String
import numpy as np

rospy.init_node('Node', anonymous=True)
pub = rospy.Publisher('/status', String, queue_size=1000)
pub.publish(String("start"))

def callback(data):
    print "Message received"
    pub.publish(String("New - status"))

def listener():

    # In ROS, nodes are uniquely named. If two nodes with the same
    # name are launched, the previous one is kicked off. The
    # anonymous=True flag means that rospy will choose a unique
    # name for our 'listener' node so that multiple listeners can
    # run simultaneously.
    rospy.Subscriber('control', Empty, callback)
    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Running"
    listener()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247735/publish-a-message-from-global-scope-in-python/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Publishers and scubscribers need a little time to properly register with the master. Thus, this publish goes into nirvana somewhere. If you put a `rospy.sleep(2.0)` before the first publish, it will work.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2